# Text input validation using ng-pattern in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, ip-address, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I want to validate a text input with ng-pattern directory in AngularJs. 
The text input can have multiple IP addresses and IP ranges with `,` (comma) separated.

for an example;

```
172.168.21.3, 172.168.45.3/8, 172.53.23.12
```

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an IP in a text field AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548351/how-to-validate-an-ip-in-a-text-field-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks, But it is for only one IP address. My scenario we can input multiple IP addresses or IP ranges with comma separated

Comment: Don't delete one question just to ask the same one again an hour later

Comment: sorry for that. I thought it did not explain much

Answer (score 0):

why not try something like this:

```
// controller
$scope.regex = /((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?),?)/g;

// markup
<input type="text" ng-model="ipAddress" ng-pattern="regex">
```

That regex should match an IP Address any number of times with a conditional comma on the end, I put together a small [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tX5xXoM5k23zGyIYzB9K?p=preview) example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it does not work for some scenarios like ;  (5.55.55.555 , 4.4.4.4 )