# Pattern validator is invalid for IP address regex

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I'm using the following regex to validate [IP address pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548351/how-to-validate-an-ip-in-a-text-field-angularjs):

```
/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/
```

I also checked it in a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/hWkEdJ/1) and it works fine.

However, when I use it in the pattern validator, valid ip addresses (e.g: 128.129.80.66) aren't recognized as valid.

**app.component.ts :**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      testForm: FormGroup;
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        const ipPattern = 
        '/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/';
        this.testForm = this.fb.group({
          inp: ['128.129.80.66', Validators.pattern(ipPattern)]
        });
      }
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="testForm">
  <input formControlName="inp"/>
  {{testForm.status}}
</form>
```

**The result:**

[image: The result]

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `Validators.pattern`, you do not need to anchor the pattern manually (no need for word boundaries, angular will enclose the whole pattern with `^` and `$` automatically) and you need to define it properly with a string literal doubling the escaping backslashes, else they will be removed by JS.

Use

```
const ipPattern = 
    "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
```

You may add `^` at the start and `$` at the end just in case you want to keep the pattern explicit (it does not do any harm to have two `^` at the pattern start and `$$` at the end, just the engine will check the start/end of the string positions twice).

*NOTE*: if you have more complex patterns with alternations, it is a good idea to use `^` and `$` explicitly in those patterns since angular automatic anchoring does not enclose the whole pattern with an optional non-capturing group, it just appends `^` and `$` to the provided pattern.