# How to mask an ipv4 address on Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a component with a input text which I need to put an IP address. I would like to know how to validate to check if its an ipv4 address, and if its possibly to mask it as well. I cannot find any component to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "masking" the IP address?

Comment: mask the user input

Comment: you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-input-mask

Comment: You can use a simple pattern validator like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176120/pattern-validator-is-invalid-for-ip-address-regex